# Regex to capture a sentence and its punctuation?

Tags: regex

I have a paragraph of text:

```
EINE ZWEIWÖCHIGE EURAIL-REISE: PARIS, SCHWEIZ UND DEUTSCHLAND
Wenn Du meinen Blog in den letzten Monaten gelesen hast, wirst Du wissen, dass ich im März diesen Jahres während meiner Frühjahresferien zwei Wochen lang durch Europa gereist bin.
Das habe ich in diesen zwei Wochen wirklich ausgenutzt!
```

I'd like to capture each sentence and its punctuation, if any.  In this example, it would include the new-line (`\n`) the period (`.`), and the exclamation point (`!`).  If the new-line character can't be captured, I'm OK with just the sentence being captured.

This pattern, `(?'s'.*)(?'p'(\.|\!))\n?`, correctly captures the last two sentences, but not the first sentence or its `\n`.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/XS3lbQ/1

Comment: there are only two sentences

Comment: OK, semantically, the first line is a title, but I still want it to be captured in the same manner.

Comment: I want the punctuation separated from the "sentence".

Comment: The group `(\.|\!)` requires there to be a `.` or a `!` in order for it to match. Some solutions to this would be to either use the `?` quantifier to make this group optional, or move the `\n` from the end into this group (turning it in to `(\.|\!|\n)`) and remove the `?` at the end.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/XS3lbQ/2

Comment: "_Frühjahr**e**sferien_" sounds unusual as compound, probably projected from terms like "_Jahreszeit_" which aren't compounds themselves. But here the dominant term is "_Frühjahr_", not "_Jahresferien_". Why not "_Frühjahr**s**ferien_"? Also: to what relates "_Das_"? If you wanted to target _Ferien_ or _zwei Wochen_ it should be "**_Die** habe ich ausgenutzt_".

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
(?'s'.*)(?'p'(?:\.|\!|\n))\n?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?'s'[^.!\n]+)(?'p'[.!\n])
```

It is more performant than the first answer. This one finishes in 25 (7+7+9+2) steps, whereas the solution in the first answer finishes in 49 (12+12+17+8) steps. You can look at the steps from the "Regex Debugger" link in the left menu of the demo.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lDDHbr/1

- `[^.!\n]` => Any character except ".", "!", and "\n"
- `[^.!\n]+` => One or more "[^.!\n]". (It captures as long as possible because it's greedy)
- `[.!\n]` => One of the ".", "!", or "\n" characters.
- `(?'s')` => Name of the capture group. ("s" is the name in this situation)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match multiple sentences on the same line, you can make the `.*` non greedy.

Then capture either a dot or exclamation mark followed by a whitespace boundary to the right, or a newline.

```
(?'s'\S.*?)(?'p'[.!](?!\S)|\n)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?'s'` Named group *s*

  - `\S.*?` Match a non whitespace char followes by any char except a newline, as few chars as possible
- `)` Close group *s*
- `(?'p'` Named group *p*

  - `[.!](?!\S)` Match either `.` or `!` and assert a whitespace boundary to the right
  - `|` Or
  - `\n` Match a newline
- `)` Close group *p*

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Px5Lek/1)